# Has Allah Ordained Holidays For People of The Book?

Tags: quran, scripture, holidays, ahlul-kitab

As we know, Allah has given Muslims Eid al Adha, Eid al Fitr and Ramadan.
As far as I’m concerned, I know that Allah has assigned fasting for the Jews and Christians because He says so in the Quran.

But what about religious holidays?
Of course Christmas has nothing to do with Christianity, but what about Hanukkah for the Jews?
We Muslims celebrate Passover like the Jews do, so does that mean Allah has also given the Jews a holiday to celebrate that is Hanukkah and acceptable in His eyes for them to do?

Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

From the Quran we know that Allah prescribed the Sabbath for the Jews ([4:154](https://quran.com/4/154?translations=20)). And that for every nation a ritual of sacrifice was ordained ([22:34](https://quran.com/22/34?translations=20)). Similarly there is mention of a festival for the Christians to celebrate the Ma'idah ([5:114](http://quran.com/5/114?translations=20)). It is also possible that there were others.

As far as these being  acceptable in Allah's eyes, then the ones He ordained were certainly acceptable if not obligatory for their specific Ummahs in the past. However nothing is acceptable from anyone now except to follow the shariah of Muhammad ﷺ.

Answer (score 0):

The traditional fasting period of Christians and Jews is 40 days before Passover/Easter. This is a biblical tradition according to Ex. 16:35.

A lesser observed Christian tradition is either 40 days before Christmas or 40 days before Advent. However, those periods it can not be compared to Ramadan as the holiday comes *after* this period. Jewish Hanukkah is very similar to Christian Advent, probably historically related. Hanukkah is definitely not a fasting holiday. Both are not biblical, not assigned by Allah.

The «assigned fasting days» mentioned in the Quran are quite certainly the 40 days before Passover.